# NgRx effect that conditionally loads data - how to handle loading flag?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I've moved from imperative actions to purely past-tense actions, and I really like how it moves app intelligence out of my components and into my Effects.  I used to use something like...

```js
this.store.dispatch(MemberActions.loadMembers());
```

...in my MemberListComponent, but with a filter on whether the data was currently loading or already loaded, etc.

Now, I'm trying the following in my component...

```
this.store.dispatch(MemberActions.memberListInitialized());
```

with the following effect...

```js
getAllMembers$ = createEffect(
() => this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(MemberActions.memberListInitialized),
    concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(MemberSelectors.isLoaded)),
    filter(([action, loaded]) => !loaded),
    switchMap(action => {
      return this.memberService.getAll();
    }),
    map((members) => MemberActions.membersLoaded({members}))
  )
);
```

I really like the indirection here, how it moves the intelligence, especially the logic to conditionally load the members, out of the component and into the effect.  The only difficulty is I can't think of an elegant/clean way to handle the loading flag on the state for this data.  I really don't want to add a reducer for memberListInitialized that also has logic to figure out if I'm actually loading members.  I can easily set loading to false in a reducer for membersLoaded, but when do I set loading to true?

Here's the state for this module...

```js
export const initialState: MemberState = {
  members: [],
  loading: false,
  loaded: false,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### Three Actions:

#### 1 for Page, 2 for API

You should have Success and Fail actions for your effect, and then you can set loading to false in the reducers for those actions.

Here's a complete example of what it could look like:

Actions:

```js
export const loadMembers = createAction('[Members Page] Load');
export const loadMembersSuccess = createAction('[MembersAPI] Load Success', props<{ members: Member[] }>());
export const loadMembersFail = createAction('[MembersAPI] Load Fail', props<{ error: string }>());
```

Effect:

```js
effectName$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(MemberActions.loadMembers),
        mergeMap(() => this.memberService.getMembers().pipe(
            map(members=> MemberActions.loadMembersSuccess({ members })),
            catchError(error => of(MemberActions.loadMembers()Fail({ error })))
        )));
});
```

Reducers:

```js
export interface MemberState {
  members: Member[]
  loading: boolean
  error: string
}
const initialState: MemberState = {
  members: [],
  loading: false,
  error: ''
}

export const memberReducer = createReducer<MemberState>(
  initialState,
  on(MemberActions.loadMembers, (state): MemberState => {
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: true
    }
  }),
  on(MemberActions.loadMembersSuccess, (state, action): MemberState => 
  {
    return {
      ...state,
      members: action.members,
      loading: false,
      error: ''
    }
  }),
  on(MemberActions.loadMembersFail, (state, action): MemberState => {
    return {
      ...state,
      members: [],
      loading:false,
      error: action.error
    }
  })
)
```

Selectors:

```js
export interface State extends AppState.State {
    members: MemberState
}

const getMemberFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<MemberState>('members')
export const getMembers = createSelector(getMemberFeatureState, state => state.member)
export const getMembersLoading = createSelector(getMemberFeatureState, state => state.loading)
```

In your constructor:

```js
this.members$ = this.store.select(getMembers)
this.loading$ = this.store.select(getMembersLoading)
this.store.dispatch(MemberActions.loadMembers())
```

### ngrx-data

Another option to avoid all this boiler plate is to use ngrx-data. The loading flag is already present  out of the box for you to use in its implementation.

Comment: This is the usual setup, but it has the significant downside of placing logic/intelligence in the dispatchers of the actions.  In my case, I have logic to conditionally load members (only if they haven't already been loaded).  By switching to purely past-tense actions (memberListInitialized) over imperative actions (loadMembers) I achieve a very nice level of indirection and a move of all intelligence into the effects.  But now I'm hoping for a clever way to handle my loading variables.  Can you provide a method to handle without relying on imperative/command actions?

Comment: @TimHardy Why wouldn't you just create a condition around the `store.dispatch`? Instead of taking away the freedom of other developers to use the store how they want? And does the response of the call to members never change? Because how would you know if it did without making the call? I'm confused, maybe I don't understand what you mean or are trying to do. You could also create a custom RxJs pipe to use in your service, or even an interceptor to prevent multiple calls if you really want to.

Comment: It's not taking away freedom, it's moving intelligence to its proper place. Commands don't make sense in NgRx because they want us to create a unique action for every source an action can come from. That means Commands break the Open/Closed principle - having to alter your effects every time you call a command from a new location. As to having two different actions for results, I'm fine with that.

Comment: @TimHardy You don't have to alter your effects if you just memo in the service (since I think that is what you are trying to do). I think NgRx should just ensure immutability and observability of state. Personally I don't feel this logic belongs in the effects. But I hope you will elaborate when you get there. I am very curious to what you come up with and whether I'd like it better.

Comment: I am learning as I go. Thank you so much for your advice. I will definitely follow up with learnings once we've put something together. I probably haven't stated my concerns very well. i.e. I think my solution is the one violating the Open/Closed principle, but my gut tells me it's worth it. Once I have a clearer picture, I will follow up.